# Powershell script for deleting folders starting with a '.' doesn't work - why?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting

I've put together a simple powershell script meant to delete specific folders:

```
gci -include .vs -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse
```

However the .vs folders don't get deleted (if the dot is removed then folders named 'vs' get removed just fine). I must be missing something.

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

Reports back:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  666
```

I run the script through the file-explorer ala 'Right Click -> Run Powershell Script'. Don't know if this makes the script run under the latest and greatest version of powershell or not.

Update:

Turns out that the culprit is that the .vs folder is marked as "read-only ". For some reason the powershell script can't delete it even the '-force' flag is indeed specified. Is there anything that can be done about this?

Comment: what version of powershell? I can't reproduce this in 5.1. It seems to work for me.

Comment: Use `-filter` instead of `-include`

Comment: I have updated the answer to mention the version of Powershell. I have tried -filter but it didn't work either. I should mention that the .vs folder is created by Visual Studio automatically when a .sln file is opened in the same directory. It's marked as readonly + hidden in the properties in case of it being of any significance.

Comment: All the nice IDEs and Text Editors do this. This folder is created to cache files and and make your experience better. Also folders starting with a `.` are hidden on *nix by default and on windows you also have to set the `hidden` attribute to true or false. This helps in case you open the project on a *nix machine.

Comment: I am aware of everything you mention. How can one automate deleting these dot-folders automagically via scripts, that's what is the issue here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention in a comment that **the directories to remove have both the `Hidden` and the `ReadOnly` filesystem attribute set**.

While `-Force` in your `Remove-Item` call *is* capable of forcing removal of items that have the `ReadOnly` attribute, **your *input* `Get-ChildItem` call requires `-Force` too, otherwise it won't find *hidden* files and folders**, so `Remove-Item` never sees them either:

```
# Note the -Force added to Get-ChildItem.
Get-ChildItem -Force -Include .vs -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
```